# Removing fieldset tab interface on a Dexterity content type

Tags: javascript, plone, dexterity, genericsetup

I need to add a condition to avoid the load of some javascript code when **adding** an object of my content type; the following condition only works when editing the object:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_javascripts">
 <javascript id="form_tabbing.js"
   expression="python:object.portal_type != 'collective.nitf.content'" />
</object>
```

This javascript code is responsible for creating the tab interface but I want to bypass it for my use case.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can solve this in a different way.

Instead of avoiding the load of the Javascript file -- which would have nasty consequences when it comes to caching and so.. -- you could avoid it from acting on your form.

The *form_tabbing.js* will look for a form element with **enableFormTabbing** class:

```
<form class="enableFormTabbing">
  <fieldset id="fieldset-[unique-id]">
    <legend id="fieldsetlegend-[same-id-as-above]">Title</legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

So, all you need to do is avoid the form of getting this **enableFormTabbing** class.

As your content type is created with Dexterity, I suggest you to override the AddForm as follows:

```
class AddForm(dexterity.AddForm):
    """Default view looks like a News Item.
    """
    grok.name('collective.nitf.content')
    grok.layer(INITFBrowserLayer)

    enable_form_tabbing = False
```

Thanks to plone.app.z3cform magic an **enable_form_tabbing** attribute will allow you to control tabbing on your form.

The same applies to the EditForm.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It should be **python:context.portal_type!='collective.nitf.content'**

Comment: Really weird since that worked for me. May be that you have typo on your portal_type ? Try install Product.Clouseau, then go into the context you want to disable the js and open a session. You then can try the expressions there until it worked for you.

Comment: This code only works when editing the content type but not when adding it: as the object still has not been created the condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Try portal_type, not meta_type with Dexterity types.  All Dexterity items have the meta_type of 'Dexterity FTI.'. This also means that OFS methods filtering on meta_type will not work and you have to use list comprehensions instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and you can also do this:

```
python:context.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_interface_info').provides('your.dotted.interface.IName')
```

Kudos Mikko! :-) http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/components/interfaces.html?#plone-interface-info

Comment: This does not work neither; it removes the javascript when adding content of whatever type and shows it when editing the object.